# $\int_0^{1/2}x^{k-l+1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})^{l-1}\arcsin(x)dx-\int_{1/2}^{1}x^{k-l+1}(\sqrt{1-x^2})^{l-1}\arcsin(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble solving this integral. Here, $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\geq l\geq 0$. I've played around with changing the limits and bringing the minus sign inside the $\arcsin$ to no avail. This is one of several similar integrals I've already solved so I know Gaussian Hypergeometric functions have been needed to solve with general $k$ and $l$. Any suggestions are much appreciated!